# How to make each process in multiprocessing.Pool handle work asynchronously

Tags: python, concurrency, parallel-processing, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that takes a long time to run and has sizable IO-bound and CPU-bound components. I need to call this function many times in a for loop, more times than the number of cores on my computer. I would like to distribute the CPU-bound components to worker processes and at the same time allow each worker process to asynchronously take in new work while it waits for the IO-bound component to complete. To give an idea of my current structure:

```
def function(args):
   IOBoundComponent()
   CPUBoundComponent()
   return 

with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10) as pool:
   results = []
   for arg in args:  # assume the length of args is >100
      results.append(pool.apply_async(function, args=(arg)))
   results = [result.get() for result in results]
```

In this current form, if I understand correctly, the 10 processes take in new iterations of the function with the new arg params as soon as they return, but can't suspend a certain iteration while the IOBoundComponent completes and go back to it once it finishes.

So, if I could get each process to start working on new args while the IOBoundComponent completes in each iteration of the loop, this would make the whole loop much quicker, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Based on some research, I think the key to this might be asyncio.Loop's run_in_executor() method, but I'm not sure how to use it properly for my problem.

Comment: You could have threading.Pool in each Process to speed up the IO bound code.  Perhaps it would be a good idea to use a multiprocessing Queue to pass the data to the working threads instead of using apply_async.  When a worker thread finishes one piece of data it grabs another one from the Queue.  It can return the results using a second Queue.  I don't see any use for asyncio since your biggest problem is the IO bound part, and asyncio won't help with that.

Answer (score 1):

You will need a two stage "run in executor" thing. First, create an ProcessPool executor with as many CPU cores you have, or possibly, up to twice as many (you can profile that later).

And then make use of the `initializer` parameter to run a function that will start (1) either a ThreadPoolExecutor in each subprocess, or an async loop and (2) a continuous function using a multiprocessing queue to dispatch tasks to the actual workers.

Then, from the main process, you submit your tasks as messages to this queue instead of submitting to the executor directly.

All in all, it is not a too-complicated design, but would take some work to organize correctly (I myself should be doing it as part of the `extrainterpreters` package I am creating).

On the main process, you will need a continuous running process that will be able to send and get results from the multi-processing queue (actually, a queue pair will be needed, one for submitting tasks, one for getting the results) -

Let's see how far I can prototype some stuff for you here. (it is a needed exercise for my own code in that package, anyway)

It turns out that the executors in "concurrent.futures'will just eventually run a target function, except for the initializer - but that one is expected to return (not loop forever). So, in order to make the 2 tiered-executor, one has to actually re-implement most of what concurrent.futures does.

Here it is - a 2-tiered Executor, that will accept async submissions in a main process, and create several sub-processes, each one with several threads controlled by an asyncio loop of its own. It could also be done only with multi-threading, and no async - but this will integrate nicely:

```
import time, concurrent.futures, threading, asyncio, multiprocessing
import sys
from queue import Empty as SyncQueueEmpty
from asyncio.queues import QueueEmpty as ASyncQueueEmpty

try:
    # only in Py 3.11
    sys.set_int_max_str_digits(1_000_000)
except AttributeError:
    pass

STOP_SENTINEL = "stop"

async def remote_worker_server(q_submission, q_results):
    async_tasks = set()
    task_registry = {}
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(10)
    stopping = False
    while not stopping or async_tasks:
        try:
            incoming_task = q_submission.get_nowait()
        except SyncQueueEmpty:
            incoming_task = None
        if incoming_task:
            id, target, args, kw = incoming_task
            if id == STOP_SENTINEL:
                stopping = True
                # Circular topology so that
                # the signal gets to all subprocesses
                q_submission.put((STOP_SENTINEL, None, None, None))
                continue

            new_task = asyncio.create_task(target(executor, *args, **kw))

            task_registry[new_task] = id
            async_tasks.add(new_task)
        if not async_tasks:
            await asyncio.sleep(0.01)
            continue
        done, async_tasks = await asyncio.wait(async_tasks, timeout=0.1, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)
        for done_task in done:
            # if task.exception():
                # TBD: arrange a protocol to pass
                # the exception information back to the main process
            q_results.put((task_registry[done_task], done_task.result()))
            del task_registry[done_task]
    # Reached when stopping has been signaled
    # and there are no pending tasks:
    return

def init_worker(q_submission, q_results):
    asyncio.run(remote_worker_server(q_submission, q_results))

class MultiplexExecutor:
    def __init__(self):
        self.task_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        self.future_queue = asyncio.Queue()
        loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
        loop.create_task(self.manager_loop())

    async def manager_loop(self):
        q_submission, q_results = multiprocessing.Queue(), multiprocessing.Queue()
        worker_processes = [multiprocessing.Process(target=init_worker, args=(q_submission, q_results)) for i in range(8)]
        for process in worker_processes:
            process.start()
        remote_tasks = {}
        pending_task_counter = set()
        id_counter = 0
        stopping = False
        while not stopping or pending_task_counter:
            try:
                target, args, kw = self.task_queue.get_nowait()
            except ASyncQueueEmpty:
                await asyncio.sleep(0)
            else:
                if target == STOP_SENTINEL:
                    q_submission.put((STOP_SENTINEL, None, None, None))
                    stopping = True
                    continue
                remote_tasks[id_counter] = f = asyncio.Future()
                q_submission.put((id_counter, target, args, kw))
                await self.future_queue.put(f)
                pending_task_counter.add(id_counter)
                id_counter += 1
            try:
                task_id, results = q_results.get_nowait()
            except SyncQueueEmpty:
                continue
            pending_task_counter.remove(task_id)
            remote_tasks[task_id].set_result(results)

    async def submit(self, target, args, kw):
        future = self.task_queue.put_nowait((target, args, kw))
        return await self.future_queue.get()

    def stop(self):
        self.task_queue.put_nowait((STOP_SENTINEL, None, None))

# USer code:

def cpubound(duration):
    start = time.monotonic()
    while time.monotonic() - start < duration:
        #this  will take ~0.1s in a 2017 era i7 core
        x = str(2 ** 300_000)

def iobound(duration):
    start = time.monotonic()
    while time.monotonic() - start < duration:
        time.sleep(0.1)


async def worker(executor, *args, **kw):
    # fot this example, we are running fixed functions -
    # but the function to be executed could be simply
    # sent as an argument over the wire.

    # also, the local executor is received as a parameter, but it could be shared by another way (as contextvar, global variable, or as an instance attribute)
    loop = asyncio.get_running_loop()
    t_cpu = loop.run_in_executor(executor, cpubound, 0.2)
    t_io = loop.run_in_executor(executor, iobound, 0.2)
    result = await asyncio.gather(t_cpu, t_io)
    # just an example return value:
    return args

async def main():
    executor = MultiplexExecutor()
    # Here one is free to run whatever code
    # in the main process, and call
    # "executor.submit" to launch a 2-tiered
    # task in subprocesses, getting back
    # an awaitable future with the result.
    futures = [await executor.submit(worker, (i,), {}) for i in range(50)]
    results = await asyncio.gather(*futures)
    executor.stop()
    return results

# guard needed to use multiprocessing
# in windows and mac:
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(asyncio.run(main()))
```